# Optimal Weight of Risky Portfolio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory

"Suppose that the investor has a quadratic utility function. That is,

$$U \left[ W \right] = W - \frac{1}{250}W^2.$$

Assume the investor is maximizing its expected utility and is
considering in investing $100 either in the risk-free asset that yields
3% per year or to a risky asset that yields 10% per year with
probability 0.5 and -2% with probability 0.5

What is the optimal weight on the risky portfolio?"

Comment: How long does it typically take to get an answer? Feels bad man :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let y be the % invested in risky portfolio.
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(W) &=& p_1W_1 + p_2W_2\\
&=&0.5(y\cdot1.1\cdot100 + (1-y)\cdot1.03\cdot100) + 0.5(y\cdot0.98\cdot100 + (1-y)\cdot1.03\cdot100)\\
&=&103+y
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(W^2) &=& p_1W_1^2 + p_2W_2^2\\
&=&0.5(y\cdot1.1\cdot100 + (1-y)\cdot1.03\cdot100)^2 + 0.5(y\cdot0.98\cdot100 + (1-y)\cdot1.03\cdot100)^2\\
&=&0.5[(103+7y)^2 + (103-5y)^2]
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(U[W]) &=& E(W) - \frac{1}{250}\ E(W^2)\\
&=&103+y-\frac{1}{500}\ [(103+7y)^2 + (103-5y)^2]\\
\frac{dEU}{dy}\ &=& 0\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
y &=& \frac{22}{37}\
\end{eqnarray*}